# Travel each object within another object in HashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, recursion, hashmap

Let's assume that `Category` might have another sub-categories in itself, and those sub-categories can have similar behaviour, and so on. How can I provide the most efficient travel to each `Category` within another `Category`?

```
public class Category {
    private Category parentCategory;
    private Map<String, Category> subcategories;
    private String name;
    // ...
}
```

The code I tried:

```
public void showSubcategoriesRecursively() {
    System.out.println(this.getName());
    if (!this.getSubcategories().isEmpty()) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Category> entry : this.getSubcategories().entrySet()) {
            entry.getValue().showSubcategoriesRecursively();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have idea how to come back to parent `Category` and take another subcategory that has not been visited yet.

I want `Category` called `Automotive` and subcategories like `Car` & `Motocycle` and `Car` has another subcategories: `Nissan` & `Toyota`. `Motocycle` has subcategories: `Aprilia` & `Suzuki` the output should be like this:

```
Automotive
         |_Car
         |   |_Nissan
         |   |      |_primera
         |   |      |_gtr
         |   |_Toyota
         |_Motocycle
                   |_Aprilia
                   |       |_rs125
                   |       |_sr150
                   |_Suzuki
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use this:

```
private static void showSubcategoriesRecursively(Category category) {
    System.out.println(category.getName());
    category.getSubcategories().values().forEach(YourClass::showSubcategoriesRecursively);
}
```

This will go recursively through all children and print the value you want.

To make it a public method of `Category` use this:

```
public void showSubcategoriesRecursively() {
    System.out.println(this.name);
    this.subcategories.values().forEach(Category::showSubcategoriesRecursively);
}
```

If you want to have the whitespaces at the beginning of the subcategories you can use this two methods in `Category`:

```
public void showSubcategoriesRecursively() {
    showSubcategoriesRecursively(0);
}

private void showSubcategoriesRecursively(int index) {
    String spaces = IntStream.range(0, index).mapToObj(i -> "\t|_").collect(Collectors.joining());
    System.out.println(spaces + getName());
    getSubcategories().values().forEach(c -> c.showSubcategoriesRecursively(index + 1));
}
```

The result will be this:

```
Automotive
    |_Car
    |   |_Nissan
    |   |   |_primera
    |   |   |_gtr
    |   |_Toyota
    |_Motocycle
    |_Aprilia
    |   |_rs125
    |   |_sr150
    |_Suzuki
```

Comment: In Java 11+, you can use `String spaces = "\t|_".repeat(index);`

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for noticing. I didn't know the `String.repeat()` method before.